# What is causing my controller endpoints to hang while CPU and Memory on AKS is not overloaded?

Tags: azure, concurrency, azureservicebus, azure-aks

I have an ASP.NET Web API solution that has some simple endpoints for retrieving and filtering records. I have a need to offload some data processing related to the records that this service is concerned with. My plan is to add a [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) to this application that will run continuously in the background to process these records. It worked fine locally, but when I deployed it to AKS it was eventually failing my liveness/readiness checks. I checked the deployed service manually while it was under load and it was hanging so I get why the Liveness/Readiness failed. I also am coming to terms that I should spin up a separate service that is solely responsible for the data processing. I don't have any issues with that, but I am confused as to why it failed when it did. I think it's because I had too many threads running simultaneously but looking at K9S at the time of failure neither memory nor CPUs are overloaded. Is it possible that there are too many threads while the CPU and memory don't seem overloaded? Or is there something else that could be going on?

For reference I am creating 50 Service Bus Clients (and Processors) for 50 separate queues. I am then sending a bunch of messages to each queue with a seperate test program. I wanted to do this just to test how it would perform under load and that's when I ran into the issue. The background service code is below for reference. For what it's worth, the background process is writing data to files and to a SQL database. However, again K9S is not showing a memory or compute overload.

```
{
    _services = services;
    _auditWriter = auditWriter;
    foreach (var queueName in QueueConfiguration.QueueNames)
    {
        var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient("<connectionString>");
        _clients.Add(serviceBusClient);
        var processorOptions = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 20,
            PrefetchCount = 20,
            ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete,
        };
        var processor = serviceBusClient.CreateProcessor(queueName, processorOptions);
        processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
        processor.StartProcessingAsync();
        _queueProcessors.Add(processor);
    }
}
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    // Through trial and error you need to await in the ExecuteAsync
    await Task.Delay(1, stoppingToken);
    stoppingToken.Register(async () =>
    {
        foreach (var processor in _queueProcessors)
        {
            await processor.DisposeAsync();
        }
    });
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Expected; no action needed
    }
    return;
}


private static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        var data = buildData(); // business logic
        try
        {
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString)) //removed connection string for post
            {
                _auditWriter.WriteAuditData(data, sqlConnection);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an exception while saving the data to the database");
        }
        
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            // use scoped variable to write files to data store
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Issue processing message for queue {args.EntityPath} | {e}");
    }
}
```

Also, here is a screenshot of the pod right after it failed the readiness check. as you can see the % on CPU is ridiculously low (maybe there's something wrong here) and the memory is only at 34%
[image]

Comment: Your ASP.NET Web API service hanging in AKS, despite low CPU, memory usage might be due to thread pool exhaustion caused by handling multiple Service Bus clients and processors. This can occur even when CPU/memory seem underutilized. Issues with SQL connection management and I/O operations during heavy load could also contribute to the service becoming unresponsive. Adjusting the concurrency settings for your Service Bus processors and separating background processing from the main service might help. Also, ensure liveness/readiness probes are configured correctly for your service's operations

Comment: I agree with the statements by Arko.   You've got a lot of concurrency going on and you're likely overloading the machine to the point where continuations for async operations are unable to be scheduled quickly enough to keep things moving forward.    You're also leaking clients that you should be disposing.

Comment: Thanks Arko and Jesse! Is there a way I can look at the number of threads. Which clients are being leaked? The Service Bus clients are initiated at the start of the background service but there is a static amount (in my case it’s 50). 

The overloading makes sense, is there a way to troubleshoot this? I assume it would be watching the number of threads. I would appreciate any tools or resources (articles for example) talking about this! Thanks again both of you!

Comment: You create the ServiceBus client instance and do not preserve the reference.  As a result, you're unable to close/dispose them when they are no longer needed, which results in connections to the service being left open until they eventually idle out.

Comment: For the thread pool, I'd suggest taking a memory dump of the process and then analyzing the async state.  For the `dotnet` CLI tooling, this is available via the `dumpasync` and the `clrthreads` view is also often helpful.  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump.   There's a few good resources in the Event Hubs Troubleshooting Guide that may also help:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#partitions-close-and-initialize-frequently.  (see end of linked section)

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding the threadpool debugging stuff. I'll take a look at that and let you know how that goes, I appreciaate it!

Comment: For the ServiceBusClients, I keep references to them in the BackgroundService's `_clients` property. Currently I'm not disposing them, but I have code that disposes the Processors in the stoppingToken's callback that I will update to dispose ServiceBusClients. Should I have more intelligent code for disposing them? Perhaps I should look into using receivers instead of processors with the number of queues I wish to monitor and creating/disposing them on some schedule.

Thanks again for all your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, it would be beneficial to have more intelligent code for managing the lifecycle of your ServiceBusClients. Consider implementing a mechanism where ServiceBusClients are disposed of properly when they're no longer needed. This helps in preventing resource leakage and maintaining efficient connection management.

Comment: Ah, that's my bad.  I overlooked stashing the client in the `_clients` collection.